# Limits of templated sub-class specialization in C++

Tags: c++, templates, subclass, template-specialization

Suppose we have code:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/xj6vhWdPf)

```
template <int Size>
struct A {
    template <typename T, typename Enable = void> struct B;
    template <> struct B<bool, std::enable_if_t<Size >= 1>> {};
    template <> struct B<short, std::enable_if_t<Size >= 2>> {};
};

template <int Size>
struct D {
    template <typename T> struct E;
    template <> struct E<bool> {};
    template <> struct E<short> {};
};

template <int Size>
struct F {
    template <typename T> struct G {};
};

template <int Size, typename T, typename Enable = void> struct C;
template <int Size> struct C<Size, bool, std::enable_if_t<Size >= 1>> {};
template <int Size> struct C<Size, short, std::enable_if_t<Size >= 2>> {};
```

Structs C and F compile well in all of CLang/GCC/MSVC. Struct D compiles well in CLang/MSVC, but has compile error in GCC. Struct A doesn't compile by all of CLang/GCC/MSVC.

GCC's error for D (similar for A):

```
<source>:19:15: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'struct D<Size>'
   19 |     template <> struct E<bool> {};
```

CLang's error for A:

```
type_traits:2514:44: error: no type named 'type' in 'std::enable_if<false>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration
    using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
```

MSVC's error for A:

```
<source>(11): error C2938: 'std::enable_if_t<false,void>' : Failed to specialize alias template
<source>(11): note: see reference to alias template instantiation 'std::enable_if_t<false,void>' being compiled
<source>(30): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'A<1>' being compiled
<source>(11): error C2913: explicit specialization; 'A<1>::B' is not a specialization of a class template
```

I have several questions:

1. Is it at all allowed in std C++ to SPECIALIZE templated sub-class? What are the limitations? Looks like GCC doesn't allow at all and CLang/MSVC allow but with certain limits.
2. Is it at all allowed to HAVE templated sub-class. If allowed then how do I specialize it? Maybe some out-of-class specialization is allowed for them (then what's the syntax)?
3. If not allowed to specialize templated sub-class then at least is it allowed to have fully-defined templated sub-class (without specializations)? Looks like struct F above uses fully-defined templated sub-class and compiles well everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why `A` doesn't work

You can notice the difference between `A` and `F`, `std::enable_if` is using `Size` for checking, but it's the template parameter of class template `A`, but not template parameter of the inner template `B` itself. If you add one as `F` does, then it'll work. E.g.

```
template <int Size>
struct A {
    template <int S = Size, typename T = void, typename Enable = void> struct B;
    template <int S> struct B<S, bool, std::enable_if_t<S >= 1>> {};
    template <int S> struct B<S, short, std::enable_if_t<S >= 2>> {};
};
```

2. Why Gcc doesn't work with `D`

It seems to be a [gcc's issue](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85282), according to [CWG 727](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#727), explicit specialization may be declared in any scope, including in class definition.

> An explicit specialization may be declared in any scope in which the corresponding primary template may be defined (10.3.1.2 [namespace.memdef], 12.2 [class.mem], 17.6.2 [temp.mem]).